# Subscribe RxJS Observable twice. Getting value of response two times

Tags: angular, rxjs

Suppose I have an Angular 2 Service. `createToken` function gets log in token from server:

```
//ANGULAR 2 SERVICE:
//login to application
createToken(email: string, password: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });

    let data = 'username=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&grant_type=password';

    this.http.post(this.loginURL, data, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            localStorage.setItem(this.storageTokenKey, response.access_token);
            console.log("Token: " + response.access_token);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error.text());
        });
}
```

I need to do two things with my token:

1. Save it to local storage (which will be done every time, so it should be in service)
2. Do some operations on it in Component (display it or whatever)

In order to do this (as far as I understand Observables), my `createToken` function has to return `Observable<>` to allow Component that will use it to call its `.subscribe` method to do some operations on result.

Unfortunately, [as I see from RxJS documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe), `.subscribe` method doesn't return `Observable<>`

What should I do then to be able to call `.subscribe()` method twice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [do() operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do):

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source.

```
return this.http.post(this.loginURL, data, { headers: headers })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .do(response => {
        localStorage.setItem(this.storageTokenKey, response.access_token);
        console.log("Token: " + response.access_token);
    });
```

Comment: This is so money. Thanks!

Comment: The pipe-able version of this is [tap](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Comment: The above `tap` link is dead. https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap